# Should ad-hoc values live in the component as class members, or not?

Tags: angular

Say we have a recipe website with a recipe-list component which loads onto itself cards of individual recipes:

```
<ul class="recipe-list">
  <li *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" (click)="displayRecipe(recipe)">
    <app-recipe-item [recipe]="recipe"></app-recipe-item></li>
</ul>
```

Within recipe-list.component.ts we can deal with the recipes in two ways:

```
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  recipes: Array<Recipe> = []; 1. Class member

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.recipes = fetchRecipes(); 1. Class member
  }
 
  fetchRecipes(): Array<Recipe> {
    return this.apiService.fetchRecipes(); // 1. Class member
  }
}
```

The other method includes the list populating itself through fetchRecipes, which directly calls the API, saving us the need for a class member and skimming the .ts by a couple lines. My question is this - which approach is better designed, and for what reasons?

I am reading The Pragmatic Programmer and wondering which approach better satisfies ETC, law of demeter, and proper access to values.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is toward using either an [Angular State Management With BehaviorSubject](https://dev.to/ngconf/angular-state-management-with-behaviorsubject-22b0) or an [NGRX Store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) for managing app data - such as your recipes array.

The component then simply subscribes to the recipes observable exposed by either of these.

The component should not get to decide when, how and from where it gets its data. Its job is to display recipes in a nice way, not to know if they need to be fetched from the API, from cache etc.

Let's say that you later create another component that allows users to add recipes. With your approach, you would need to re-visit the Recipes List component and change its code to ensure that it displays the new recipe. But when the recipes are exposed through an observable by a state store, your Recipes List component will just get the updated list - without you having to add any additional code for that.